# Offline / Online Hybrid Java (Spring Boot) application

Tags: java, spring-boot, offline, hybrid

I've an issue, which I am trying to tackle with my team.
We have a monolith application with a database(MySQL), a backend and a frontend.
This application is working as a web-app, but also as a desktop application (via electron).
We are now also trying to create an Android and iOS variant for this application.
The newest feature request is that the application should work offline as well on the desktop application, the Android and the iOS application.

Does anyone know how transform an full online application which works on these platforms to a hybrid, offline/online variant...

We are using Java Spring Boot + React for the web app and the desktop app.
For Android and iOS we are using Java + React Native

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too general. Please include at least a diagram of your application's architecture. Preferably in the Simon Brown C4 standard (level C2). Please also describe what functionalities you have problems with when going online -> offline and what exactly you mean by that.

Comment: I agree with @Reveson 's comment. Please add more details so we can help you.

Comment: I will try to give some more information haha sorry. At the moment the application is online only, but we need the application to work offline as well. The problem is that it wasn't accounted for that we needed an offline application as well, which should work multi platform at the same time. The application is already as good as done for the online mode, including a db, which works with mysql a backend and frontend which are run on a server. The only option I see to have an offline version is to have the full package of the application locally on a mobile/latop device)